# Download symbols from Microsoft symbol server

Tags: windows, windbg, symbol-server

I read [MSDN "using symbol server"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/ee416588(v=vs.85).aspx#using_the_microsoft_symbol_server)

I am trying to download symbols from microsoft symbol server.

My symbol search path: `srv*C:\symbols*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols`

In WinDbg I always get error:

```
************* Symbol Loading Error Summary ************** 
Module name            Error 
ntdll                  PDB not found :
srv*c:\symbols*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
                Unable to locate the .pdb file in this location

                       PDB not found : > srv*c:\symbols*https://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
                Unable to locate the .pdb file in this location
```

How can I obtain the symbols from MS symbol server?

Comment: Is it only `ntdll`? Sometimes the symbol server is a little out of date... Either way, try `.symfix` instead of manually setting the symbol path.

Comment: Related if not duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45013392/480982

Answer (score 2):

because the location site is crashed!
http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
open that in your browser,you will see a crashed page,normally it will show a hint page if the site is good.
i try to report this but cannot find the way.-_-!!!
that brought me some trouble too.

question:is there a site cached MS symbols and opened for everyone?thanks.

Comment: open that site browser will show a page like you said if the site work good,but now it will show me a crash page,inner service crash page.you can try to open that to verify what i say.

Comment: I fully understand what you said,and i kwnow the user agent is "Microsoft-Symbol-Server/10.0.0.0",When I write my own pdb downloader,that site is browserable,it will show a page with message like "this site is not browserable,try to use the provided helpers like symchk or windbg.....",but now it shows a page with "ExceptionType":"System.ArgumentNullException",clearly,this is an internal web service error.I never said i can download pdb with browser on that site.Well,Let's stop arguing here,thanks for your comments.